# 404 not found error shows when i run as java application

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, tomcat, servlets

[image]
here is my servlet class

```
package login.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet(name = "LogoutServlet", urlPatterns = {"/LogoutServlet"})
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public LogoutServlet() {
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.invalidate();

        out.println("Thank you,you are successfully logged out");
        out.close();
    }
```

here is web.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.39</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </dependency>
```

}

in springboot project i have to run as java application but it gives 404 error,while when i run as  run on server it totally works..what should i do?

Comment: @Metroids ...............

Answer (score 0):

I think you build the project as WAR, in this case the right way is to start the application in a servlet container(such as Tomcat), and not run as java application.